What can cause horizontal flickering lines like these on an HDMI connected monitor?
I have a new ThinkPad P16v Gen 2 laptop connected to two external Acer S240HL monitors (one via HDMI and one via Display Port) via a Thinkpad Thunderbolt 4 Workstation Dock. After a couple of weeks of using this setup, I start getting the occasional flickering horizontal lines on the HDMI connected monitor.

It gradually gets worse to the point where I contact the supplier (since this is all new an under warranty).
After getting me to update the firmware on the dock and check that the BIOS on the new laptop is also up-to-date, and these things not fixing anything, they send a replacement dock. After a couple of weeks this dock also degrades in the same way.
Other things about my setup.

Plugging the HDMI monitor into the laptop HDMI port directly never shows the issue ran this way for couple of weeks while waiting for new dock, and never saw the issue. This suggests that the monitor, laptop and HDMI cable are not at fault?
Switching from new dock back to old (which has sat unused for 2 weeks) and immediately saw the issue again, suggesting a permanent form of degradation.
Problem appeared "fixed" when starting to use the new dock, suggesting not a problem with laptop or HDMI cable?

I am left with the impression that the supplier does not know what to do with my problem since they are generally ignoring most of my emails, so seeking advice from experts elsewhere. What kind of thing can go wrong and cause this kind of flickering? Has anyone else experienced this kind of problem with a dock?

I agree it seems like the issue is with the dock. But I have had the same issue with now 2 instances of the dock. The supplier does not seem to know about this being a known issue, and I am not really sure what to try next while I wait for them.

Also, don't rule out cables. See if you can test this with other cables and see if this improves the problem, makes it worse, or that it changes nothing. If its not changing anything, the cables are fine.

I also wondered about cables when the first dock went bad, but having got a replacement that was good for the first few weeks, and still using all the same cables, that, to me anyway, suggested there was nothing wrong with the cables. I am curious whether my logic is correct though. Could there be something wrong with cables that would show up in this way, like it's the cables causing the dock to go bad?

It could be that the cable is degraded in some way, and that by completely unplugging it, plugging it back in somehow temporarily resolves it. It is definitely something you should check by replacing the cables. It can be a faulty dock for sure, but 2 completely new docks going bad in a short time, while it definitely could be, sounds off to me.
